# Date Conversion in SSIS - JSON string date to datetime

Tags: ssis

Is there a way in SSIS to convert this

```
2015-10-13T21:03:23.139Z
```

to DateTime?

The Date above is coming from the mongoDB document as

"createdON" : ISODATE("2015-10-13T21:03:23.139Z")

Comment: None of the Date transformations can do it in SSIS. I can do this by using substring and parse individual parts but I am looking for one-liner. Whoever gave -1 on question is immature and doesn't know the solution and in my dictionary is a loser who spends his time on down voting. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I ended up using third party tool (Zappysys) to read MongoDB source and it worked perfectly fine. There is no built in feature in SSIS to parse the above datetime string value.

Comment: Cozyroc also provides awesome tools for SSIS